# Is Jiren able to use Ultra Instinct?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Jiren was able to dodge Hit's time skip attacks and predict his movement pattern.
He also appears to be as strong as a God of destruction.
Many Gods try to achieve Ultra Instinct and some of them still struggling to master it.
Is there an indication of Jiren achieving or even mastering UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main concept of Ultra Instinct, is cutting down reaction time **significantly**. We know this based on Whis's comments while training Goku and Vegeta. Also, Vados's comment during Goku vs Kefla.
It was also stated by Vados, that **Jiren's** reaction time is near to perfect. We can conclude the same based on the last comment she made when Hit attacked Jiren after Jiren defeated Goku. She said that most warriors are open immediately after fighting an enemy and Jiren didn't even have that weakness and he reacted immediately to block hit. We also see Jiren being able to dodge the first **Kick** from **Ultra Instinct Goku**.
We also see in the Ultra Instinct state, Goku was doing fairly well with Jiren despite Jiren's physical power being significantly higher compared to Goku's. So in other words, the transformation made Goku's reaction time better than Jiren which is why Jiren had trouble landing attacks.  However, Jiren's **reaction time** is extremely good enough to easily react to **Hit's time skip** and his attack which Goku couldn't that easily.
I believe every **God Tier fighter** , ie God's of destructions and Jiren have require very minimal time to react and hence have UI mastered down to an extent. However, it is not to the same extent as that of Whis and the other angels and Goku has possibly mastered the dodging part, to the same extent as Whis.  The reason why I believe Jiren hasn't perfected it as much as Goku has is because of something said by **Whis during the UI Goku vs Kefla fight** . Whis said that Goku's attacks were pretty weak and this was even after he powered up. During his fight against Jiren, we know Jiren in terms of raw power is comparable to a God of Destruction's power. Hence if **Jiren's reaction time was better than Goku's or even equal to Goku's**, he wouldn't even have struggled a little against UI Goku.
This brings me to my conclusion that Jiren **has not mastered self movement**. I believe he has a reaction time which is very comparable to that of a God. However, Goku is ahead of him with regard to that. Jiren's raw power on the other hand, is superior to Goku and comparable to Beerus and the other Gods.

Comment: So is it that he can't use it or that he did not master it completely. I got confused a little.

Comment: I believe Ultra Instinct is a state where your body can perfectly react out of instinct 100%. So your reaction time is at its lowest. We see Beerus utilize an imperfect version of the same in the Manga. I think Jiren is at that stage. Not perfected it to the same extent Goku has.